# Solution to Hamilton-Jacobi differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $H(x,y)$ be a $C^2$ function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $(x(t),y(t))$ be a solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi equations $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}H(x(t),y(t))$$$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(x(t),y(t))$$
>
> Show that the function $H$ is constant along the integral curves of the equations above.

I'm not so sure what "$H$ constant along the integral curves" means. Does it mean $H(x(t),y(t))$ is a constant value for any $t$? If so, how to proceed in proving that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By integral curve they mean a solution to the system.

Suppose $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ is a solution, then let $\phi(t) = H(x(t),y(t))$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\phi}(t) &=& \frac{\partial H(x(t),y(t))}{\partial x} \dot{x}(t) + \frac{\partial H(x(t),y(t))}{\partial y} \dot{y}(t) \\
&=& (-\dot{y}(t)) \dot{x}(t) + (\dot{x}(t)) \dot{y}(t) \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

It follows that $\phi$ is constant.

Comment: To copper.hat: once again we run in the same race, me bucko!  I type from the Cafe Mediterraneum; you know the place?

Comment: @RobertLewis: My #1 favourite cafe for about 30 years. Usually Sunday mornings when I can make it. Then Moe's to scour the mathematics book section...

Comment: To copper.hat:  ha! how did I know?  Email me next time you're in the 'hood--my email address is in my profile--and we can have coffee!  My favorite since '72, when I first entered and sat at the "Dustin Hoffman" table!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Will do!

Comment: To copper.hat:  Nice!  I'll get it on my 'droid--a "smart"??? phone!  Except the one thing it won't do smartly is *phone*!

Comment: To copper.hat:  how about a math.stackexchange Halloween gathering--we can meet these ghouls face to face!

Comment: @RobertLewis: SE doesn't seem big on social!

Comment: To copper.hat:  maybe not, but you have to admit it would be amusing, and probably *perfect* for Halloweeny!

Comment: @RobertLewis: I imagine Caffe Med must be interesting on Halloween!

Comment: To copper.hat:  I'm sure; I'm sure I'll find out.  Rumors of party are floating around, but what will actually transpire who knows?  *Something* amusing, not doubt, even if only the T-graph ambience.  But we'd best cut this short, the automated comment nazi is looking over my shoulder!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Just to annoy the comment nazi :-).

Comment: To copper.hat:  ***Not That!!!***

Answer (score 3):

$$
\dot{H} = H_{x}\dot{x} + H_{y}\dot{y} = H_{x}H_{y} + H_{y}\left(-H_{x}\right) = 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

The equations in the question are *Hamilton's equations*; the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is related, though different, see [this Widipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation).  In any event, we have

$\frac{dH}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \dot x + \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} \dot y = \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial y} (-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}) = 0, \tag{1}$

which from an elementary perspective says the the integral curves $(x(t), y(t))$ of

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}H(x(t),y(t)), \tag{2}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(x(t),y(t)), \tag{3}$

run orthogonal to $\nabla H$, so they lie in surfaces of constant $H$.  A more advanced treatment requires the use of *symplectic forms* and *symplectic mechanics*, information about which is easily found *via* google, widipedia, etc.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***